# Moodle - kind of drag test

Tags: moodle

I'd like to make the test that would look like:

[image]

You have to drag and drop the words into right categories. There is a kind of quiz "drop and drag onto the image" in Moodle, but there is a problem that each possibility has only only one right room to place. But in my test doesn't matter on rank, only on the right category.

Concretely: The dog and the lion belong to the category animals. But it doesn't matter if the dog is the first or second. Is any possibility to solve this?